# Why a lot of red lines in visual studio

Tags: f#

I am trying to learn f# and copy some sample from internet. When copy to visual studio, it shows me a lot of red line as show in the following picture.

[image]

Comment: Namespace not found. You may need to add reference to the required dll

Comment: Red lines show errors. To deactivate go to preferences and deactivate the function.

Comment: You should add the reference to System.Xml.Linq.dll to the project or refer it using #r "System.Xml.Linq" in F# script file

Comment: You need to add a reference to the `System.Xml.Linq` assembly in your project.

Comment: I did everything what you mentioned above. But still red line occurs.

Comment: Those red lines have error messages associated with them. In the future, asking questions about the specific error messages instead of "red lines" will get you quicker, better responses, and make your question (and the answers) searchable by people who are typing those same specific error messages into Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of your objects (like [`XName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`XElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) are belonging to classes defined in the assembly `System.Xml.Linq.dll`.
The line `open System.Xml.Linq` is the C# equivalent line `using System.Xml.Linq;` that allows you to use the methods defined in the referenced assembly in your code.

If the assembly is not referenced (you didn't add the reference to `System.Xml.Linq` to the project), you have that error.

Remember that you can reference (as @Petr said), if you're using F# script files or F# interative, the assemblies you want using: `#r "AssemblyNameHere"`. Other info about scripting and this option in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrsmith/archive/2008/09/12/scripting-in-f.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Hover mouse over the red squiggles and a tooltip will popup. That tooltip explains what assembly you should reference.